# Combine rleid grouping in R if two groups are within certain distance from each other

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, grouping, cluster-analysis

I have a data frame which monitors changes in patients vitals.

The readings are then classified using a traffic light system (green, amber and red).

I am currently using the `rleid` function to add a group ID variable to my data frame.

I can then separate the number of occurrences that the data is in the red category and can do the following :

1. work out how long each event lasted
2. what the min and max readings were etc.

However, I would like to combine any red categories which happen within 12 hours of each other (46 data points).

Take the following example:

```
Date=seq(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2015-01-31 23:45:00"), by="15 min")
Data=c(rnorm(750,1,2),rnorm(100,4,2), rnorm(10,1,1),rnorm(50,4,2.5),rnorm(500,0,1),rnorm(600,6,2),rnorm(26,1,2),rnorm(940,6.5,2))
Class=c(rep("Green",750), rep("Red",100),rep("Green",10),rep("Red",50), rep("Green",500),rep("Red",600),rep("Green",26),rep("Red",940))

DF=data.frame(Date,Data,Class)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
DF$GroupID=rleid(DF$Class)

ggplot(DF,aes(Date,Data,colour=Class,group=1))+geom_line()
```

In my data frame, I have 4 red clusters,

but I would like there to be only two 'red' groups since there are less than 46 'green' data points between the clusters.

Is there any way to specify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of the number of rows of each of the Green and Red Groups, and whereever the number of rows for a Green group is less than 46, change it to Red

To ensure the previous Group was a 'Red', we can add a column to tell us the 'Class' of the previous group

```
## One way to do this: 
## - get the first row for each group, then shift it back one to give us the class for the previous row
## - then join it all back together
dt_previous <- DF[order(Date), .I[1], by=.(GroupID)]
dt_previous[, V1 := V1 - 1]

## Get the previous Class according to the new V1/row index
dt_previous[ , previous_class :=  c(NA, DF[dt_previous$V1, as.character(Class)]) ]
## Join the 'previous_class' onto DF
DF <- dt_previous[, .(GroupID, previous_class)][ DF, on=c("GroupID")]

## define the number of rows for each group
DF[, nRows := .N, by=.(GroupID)]

## Update 'Green' to 'Red' where nRows < 46
DF[ nRows < 46 & Class == "Green" & previous_class == "Red", Class := "Red"]

## Redefine the groups
DF[, GroupID := rleid(Class)]

ggplot(DF, aes(Date, Data, colour=Class, group=1)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: That's a good idea - thanks. I wonder if its possible to also add the constraint that the previous group has to be red for this rule to apply? That way, if the class goes from "Green" to "Orange" for example, I would like this to stay "Green", even if this is only for a small number of points.

Comment: @sym246 - Of course! Please see my edit. There may be a more elegant way, but this should get you going

Comment: Thank you @Symbolix, this is great!

Comment: @sym246 - `setDT(DF)` doesn't need to be assigned to anything as it updates `DF` [by reference](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html)

Comment: This does not work anymore, throws the error: "Error in `[.data.frame`(DF, order(Date), .I[1], by = .(GroupID)) : 
  unused argument (by = .(GroupID))"